# CsvHelper: cycle detected when i try to install the nuget package

Tags: c#

I am trying to install the CsvHelper nuget package in a project to can read CSV files.

I am trying to install it with the nuget manager, but I get the error: Restore package failed. Cycle detected: CsvHelper -> CsvHelper (>= 30.0.1).

How could I install this library?

How I get the error:

- I create a .NET 7 console application named CsvHelper
- I open manage nuget packages (right click in the project)
- I search for CsvHelper
- I install it
- I get the error

Thanks.

Comment: do you already have CsvHelper  in your project?

Comment: CsvHelper [doesn't have a dependency on itself](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/#dependencies-body-tab) either directly or indirectly. What does your `csproj` look like? Do you have a project named `CsvHelper` in your solution? Are you using some *other* NuGet package that depends on CsvHelper? Try creating a new console project and add `CsvHelper` to it. You'll see it works fine. Then try adding the other packages in your project until you find which one causes the problem

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to reproduce the problem, much less offer a solution. Adding `CsvHelper` to a project works fine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No repro. I actually tried this myself before answering, in the off-chance that a NuGet package with millions of downloads would have such a problem. NuGet says there were 1M downloads of the current version

Comment: Don't call your project `CsvHelper`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried with a project named CsvHelperTest instead of CsvHelper and it works.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía .... don't call your project the same as another project then. *Your own code* is referencing the wrong namespace and wrong project when it tries to use classes in the `CsvHelper` namespace. You'd get the same issues if you created two projects with the same namespace and class names referencing one another.